# Plotting Data Points Yields Strange Result

Tags: plotting, data

I want to plot a rather big amount of data points. About 16000 points. I'm still a newbie to Mathematica so I hope it's just a simple mistake.

Heres a minimal example:

```
 data0 = Import["Data.txt", "table"]
```

[image: Resulting Data]

```
p1 = ListPlot[data0, PlotStyle -> {Green}]
```

[image: Plot]
I should get several peaks. But I only get this mess of points and I have no idea why. Maybe too many points? Strangely the y-axis stops at about 8 but there are points which have values above 5000.

If I plot the same data with python I get [image: python plot] 
Which is the sort of graph I would expect.

I would really appreciate some help!

Greetings

Comment: Please provide your data as MMA code !

Comment: I can't insert the data as raw text in the post since it would be more than 30000 characters. And it seems that I can't upload txt files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
ListPlot[
  data0,
  PlotRange -> Full
  PlotStyle -> Green
]
```

Mathematica will quite often decrease the range to display “interesting” things near the baseline of the data/function. This is rarely what I want, so I usually add `PlotRange -> Full`.

Comment: It worked! I'm glad it was that simple. Thank you!